# jQuery - I can't get select value

Tags: jquery

I want to post my form data and images with dropzonejs. I'm able to get my input and select values as well except cities_id.

When a user selects a country, I'm fetching the cities about the country and show them on select fields. Even if a user selected a city, I can't get this cities_id. it seems undefined in ajax request's parameters.

**Select form**

```
<div class="col-sm-12 col-md-3">
  <select id="country" class="select2" name="country_id">
    <option value="0">Select a country</option>
     <?php $get_country = $db->prepare("SELECT * FROM country ORDER BY id ASC");
     $get_country->execute();
     while ($fetch_country = $get_country->fetch(PDO::FETCH_ASSOC)) { 
     ;?>           
     <option value="<?php echo $fetch_country['id'] ;?>">
        <?php echo $fetch_country['name'] ;?>
     </option>
     <?php } ;?>
  </select>
</div>
<div class="col-sm-12 col-md-3">
          <select id="city" class="select2" name="city_id">
          </select>
</div>
```

**dropzonejs send form data**

```
myDropzone.on('sendingmultiple', function (file, xhr, formData) {

 $("form input, form select").each(function () {
          formData.append($(this).attr("name"), $(this).val());
       }
     formData.append('name', $('#summernote').summernote('code'));
});
```

How can I get cities_id value from my select form ?

Comment: What is the result if you select cities_id using jquery?

Comment: it say undefined

Comment: Yes, in your code i cannot see any code that will load data to cities select, it should  have sme code like country_id to load cities

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I have recreated something similar and it seems to work. I get two alerts. "B" then "C".

Have you checked that the option tags added via AJAX have valid `value` attributes and there is no malformed HTML?

When you add the `<option>` elements are you replacing the whole `<select id="city"></select>` using AJAX or just populating the existing select with new `<option>` elements?

Which browser and version of jQuery are you using?

Here is my (partial) code

```
<select name="sel1">
    <option value="A">A</option>
    <option value="B">B</option>
</select>

<select name="sel2"></select>

<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/3.3.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<script>

    imageDropzone.on('sendingmultiple', function(a,b,c) {
        $('select').each(function() {
            alert($(this).val());
        });
    });

    $('[name=sel1]').on('change', function() {
        addOpt();
    });

    function addOpt() {
        $.get('options.html', null, function(){
            $('[name=sel2]').append('<option value="C">C</option>');
        });
    }
</script>
```